# Convert FrameLayout to jpeg file

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-framelayout

I've been trying to convert a FrameLayout that contains an image and some text to a bitmap then export it as a jpg, while this was successful, the resulting jpg is pretty low quality.

This is how I've done it:

```
public Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

private void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/Test");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image" + n + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();  

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    Bitmap image = viewToBitmap(frameLayout);
    saveImage(image);
```

Is there any way to export the same FrameLayout in a much higher quality? Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are doing this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I hope it's going to be much clear now.

Comment: Unless you are showing a photo, use PNG, not JPEG.

Comment: Okay I've changed it to PNG but the result is pretty much the same, although the file size is bigger, the photo is still pixelated

Comment: You might want to upload a screenshot of your UI, along with a copy of the PNG. You are new here on Stack Overflow, so I don't think you have the rights to upload directly, but you could upload somewhere else and link to them here. Using `draw()` and a `Canvas` should be fine.

Comment: Sure, here are the screenshots, https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g9tkm07rvxljrl3/AABy7eglN-NkAEZVWJn-mc4ya?dl=0

Comment: I guess I don't see what the problem is. Other than the text being different, the images appear the same, including the anti-aliasing (or whatever) issues with your grid.